# Selectively reset the color of the surface after blitting PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have two green surfaces

```py
s1 = Surface((100, 100))
s2 = Surface((100, 100))

s1.fill((0, 255, 0))
s2.fill((0, 255, 0))
```

Then i blit them on main surface with beautiful background

```py
screen.blit(image.load("ocean.png").convert_alpha(), (0, 0))
screen.blit(s1, (0, 100))
screen.blit(s2, (200, 100))
```

Result:

[image: Result]

*Question*: **How can i selectively reset the color of one of the green surfaces after i have already blitted this surface on another surface**? As if this surface never existed.

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Note:

PyGame methods `set_alpha` and `set_colorkey` don't change anything. In addition, they will not allow to reset the surface selectively.

```py
screen.set_alpha(0) # no changes
```

Or

```py
sreen.set_colorkey((0, 255, 0)) # no changes
```

Comment: When you blit your are overwriting what's on the screen with something new. The only way to revert that is to redraw the background and left square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i selectively reset the color of one of the green surfaces...?

**This is impossible**

Each object in the scene is drawn to the `pygame.Surface` object associated with the display. `screen` is a `pygame.Surface` object and `blit` is short for block image transfer.
You cannot "reset" the color to a previous state. Each pixel of a surface knows only one color, the current color. However, you can `blit` a part of the original background on the rectangular area:

```py
background = image.load("ocean.png").convert_alpha()
```

```py
screen.blit(background, (200, 100), area=pygame.Rect(200, 100, 100, 100))
```